# Задача с долларам в JS

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять как сделать -

Один доллар стоит 27 гривен. Вывести данные с расчетом стоимости 10, 20, 30... 100 долларов

let dollrs = 27;

Comment: `for(var i = 10; i < 110; i+= 10) console.log(i, i * 27)`

Answer (score 1):

По описанию непонятно что конкретно нужно :) если нужно указать сколько гривен есть, курс доллара, и сколько на выходе выйдет долларов - то это "сумма разделенная на курс". Например:

```js
function UAHtoUSD(value, rate) {
  return (value / rate).toFixed(2)
}

console.log(UAHtoUSD(1000, 27))
```